How can I find the values if the passed parameter can be null?
I have a query select id from tasks where name = $1. The value for $1 is passed from the application and it can be null.  As far as I understand, with name = null, the query will not give the correct result. Is there any way to modify the query so that it takes both the filled value and null? Or I need to write two queries like
if (name == null) {
   select id from tasks where name is null
} else {
   select id from tasks where name = $1
}

Update
maybe I didn't explain it correctly. I have a table
id  |  name
____________
1   |  task1
2   |  null
3   |  null
4   |  task4

The application executes the code
query("select id from tasks where name = $1", name)

The variable name can be null, or it can be equal to another value.
Now it turns out like this:
if name = null: query("select id from tasks where name = $1", name) 
in db:  select id from tasks where name = null. Expected id =2 and id = 3. Actual - 0 rows

if name = task1: query("select id from tasks where name = $1", name) 
in db:  select id from tasks where name = 'task1'. Expected id =1. Actual id =1

WHERE name = $1 OR name IS NULL does not seem to be correct, since if name = task1, I will get id =1, 2, 3, but I need only 1

WHERE name = $1 OR name IS NULL;

You seem to be looking for the IS NOT DISTINCT FROM operator instead of the = operator:
SELECT id FROM tasks WHERE name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $1;

It's a bit verbose but does what you want.

Unfortunately it cannot use an index.

@LaurenzAlbe Not even if $1 is not null?

Even then, as far as I know.

Bergi's answer is correct, but if you need an index to support the query, there is an alternative trick you could use.
Identify a string constant that can never occur as name (I randomly pick @@@). Then you can use
WHERE coalesce(name, '@@@') = coalesce($1, '@@@')

The index that can speed that up is
CREATE INDEX ON tasks (coalesce(name, '@@@'));

